# Entity interpolation with a Unity listen server

Tags: c#, unity, networking

How can this be done? I've implemented client side interpolation but I'm at a loss on how to implement it on a listen server. In order for the listen server player to see the same thing as the clients, it needs to display it's past positions.

The problem with this is, as far as I know, there's no way to specify positions for rendering and positions for collision and everything else in Unity. transform.position is used for everything. Is there a way to draw in a different position?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to making an authoritative server? If so, only the server has the real positions of all players, and all remote players only see approximations (via proxy) of the world state. So in fact no one but the server really "sees" the exact positions of all the players, since network latency is in play.

Comment: If this is indeed the case, I suggest you go and read some materials online as this is a complex issue - some links: [Great lecture by Bungie](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014345/I-Shot-You-First-Networking) [The famous Gaffer on Games blog](http://gafferongames.com/) [Another great blog post](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/fast_paced_multiplayer.html)